# Restricting outlook search to a specific TO list

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is it possible to restrict search in outlook to only a specific TO list?
Example:
When I type in the search criteria

```
TO:(Bob AND Jean)
```

it finds all emails where both Bob and Jean are in the TO list, apart from other people.
I want to find all emails that were sent ONLY to Bob and Jean. Exclude emails where there are other people in the TO list.

```
System Info:
Microsoft Outlook, Microsoft Office Professional Plau 2013
Windows 8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is too granular. It can not be done. The Sent To field looks for e-mails in the the TO or CC. It will look for any e-mails where Bob or Jean are in the TO or CC. You can perform a search based on the message header, but you'd need many variations of Bob and Jean that it would not be very practical. You can filter e-mails sent only TO you, but not sent TO other specific people.

Comment: how do I achieve "You can filter e-mails sent only TO you" using search strings?

Comment: It is a custom search option.